# Else case in conditional compile in rust

Tags: rust

How can I have some code being compiled only when no cfg block match? For example something like this:

```
#IF NUM == 1
//something
#ELSE IF NUM == 2
// something
#ELSE
// no case match, panic!
#ENDIF
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By hand e.g.

```rust
#[cfg(thing1)]
// something
#[cfg(all(not(thing1), thing2))]
// something
#[cfg(all(not(thing1), not(thing2)))]
// no case
```

Alternatively, within a function and if your "something"s are compilable in every case, you can use `cfg!`. Since it evaluates to a literal there's a good chance the optimiser will strip out the bits which don't match:

```rust
if cfg!(thing1) {
    // something
} else if cfg!(thing2) {
    // something
} else {
    panic!();
}
```

although [`compile_error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.compile_error.html) would make more sense than panic.

There is also [a `cfg-if` crate](https://crates.io/crates/cfg-if) for something more ergonomic.

For more on the topic, see the article [Yak shaving conditional compilation in Rust](https://bitshifter.github.io/2020/05/07/conditional-compilation-in-rust/) which expands on and discusses the various approaches.

Comment: `cfg!` evaluates values at compile time but you need to check these values at runtime, for example you cannot separate windows specific  and linux specific code via using `if cfg!( .. else`

Comment: "for example you cannot separate windows specific and linux specific code" that depends on what is being done exactly, this is limited to code which can compile in every branches but there are situations where it works fine e.g. different embedded assembly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not` in the conditional part of a `cfg` block. You can see an example in the docs for [cfg](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html)

```
// This function only gets compiled if the target OS is linux
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
fn are_you_on_linux() {
    println!("You are running linux!");
}

// And this function only gets compiled if the target OS is *not* linux
#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
fn are_you_on_linux() {
    println!("You are *not* running linux!");
}
```

If you need something more complicated you can also use `any` and `all`, something like:

```
#[cfg(target_os="linux")]
fn get_os() -> &str { return "Linux"; }

#[cfg(target_os="windows")]
fn get_os() -> &str { return "Windows"; }

#[cfg(not(any(target_os="linux", target_os="windows")))]
fn get_os() -> &str { return "Unknown"; }
```

Further details are available in the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html).